# cross domain ajax call over SSL with windows auth fails on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, ssl, windows-authentication, cors

I have a web app using windows authentication that makes a call to a web service using windows authentication on a different server on our intranet. Specifically, I am making an ajax call with jQuery cross-domain with SSL to a WCF rest service (`WebHttpBinding`).

I have solved the cross domain issue by setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the web service. And in the jquery call for i.e. by setting `$.support.cors = true;`.

I have solved the problem of sending the credentials by setting the header `("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")`; in the web service and in jQuery call by setting

```
$.ajaxSetup({ xhrFields: { withCredentials: true, crossDomain: true

        }
    });
```

I had this working for both IE and Chrome, making a cross domain to the websevice using Windows authentication from the web app using windows authentication running on a different server. However, when I added SSL to both sides (https to https) , the call no longer worked in IE. It continued to work in Chrome.

Looking at the http traffic in Fiddler, it appeared that the browser was not even sending out the request, that is, Fiddler had no entry that showed the request had been made at all. By debugging the javascript, I could trap an error coming back from the jquery call and the status text was "access denied". But as I say, it didn't appear to me that the browser was even sending the request out to the web service.

I tried a jquery cors plug-in `jQuery.XDomainRequest.js`. At that point I began to see the http call in fiddler. It was a single 401 "Access Denied". And that was it. It did not appear that the client call was sending any credentials along.

Previous to that, before I added the SSL, I would see a 401 with response header for the authenication credentials. Followed by a 200 where the request headers included the windows auth credentials. So it worked.

But now (in IE) I was only getting the single 401. So I am stuck, I need to make the call

1. cross domain,
2. with windows auth,
3. with SSL and
4. with IE.

I can get everything to work up to the combination of all four of the requirements together. I am mystified why I can get cross domain with windows auth to work with IE, but I cannot get it to work when I add SSL.

It works fine in Chrome so it must be something about the XDomainRequest object. Is there any way I can tweak the jQuery call in order to get this all to work. Has anyone heard of this particular issue before? Is this surmountable? or am I simply knocking my head against the wall?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the OP's problem was just an IE9 problem, but I had a bit of trouble getting this to work in modern browsers as well. I discovered that you can not use `*` for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header if you need windows authentication to work.

The cross-domain server (target of the ajax request) needs to fully specify the host server (domain where the ajax call is coming from) in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Perhaps the OP was doing this, but for me it was the missing piece. I now have jQuery ajax, with `xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }`, and the usual CORS headers, and it works for IE11, https, windows auth, cross domain. It also works in other browsers. It works with get and post.

Another issue I ran into... I was setting my CORS headers only on "OPTIONS" requests, but this sometimes wasn't working, so I just add those headers to every request now. I am just adding these in my ASP.NET MVC `Application_BeginRequest` method as follows.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://portal");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

Here is a snippet of the JavaScript side

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<a url in here>"
    type: "POST",
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: payload,
    success: success,
    error: function (data) {
        logFailure(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

XDomainRequest explicitly forbids the use of authentication; see #5 here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

It's not clear how the JQuery cross-domain call works in IE9 and below, which do not support CORS *except* through the XDomainRequest object. In IE10, this should work just fine.